# How to find out in which commit a file is removed?

Tags: git

I got one file removed in the repository. I want to find out on which commit this file is removed. How can I do this?

Answer (score 8):

`git rev-list -n 1 HEAD -- <file_path>`

This will return the hash of the last commit that has modified this path. If your file does not exist in HEAD anymore, it means that it will return the hash of the deleting commit.

Good luck

Answer (score 6):

```
git log -p -1 -- <file_path>
```

It will show the detail of the commit.

Answer (score 4):

If you do not know the specific path of the (now missing) file you can also do

```
git log --name-status
```

This will give you all the last commits and which files where added/removed/modified by those commits. Therefore you can simply use your pager search feature (like `/` on less) to look out for the commit in question.

If you know in which subdirectory the file used to be you can add this to restrict the shown commits to those working on files in that directory:

```
git log --name-status -- directory
```